# SBT equivalent of Ant target

Tags: scala, ant, sbt, target

What is the SBT equivalent (if any) of Ant targets? For example, a snippet in a build.xml file for Ant would be:

```
<target name="runClient" description="run client">
    <java classname="client.Client" fork="true">
        <jvmarg value="-Djava.rmi.server.codebase=${client_web_codebase}"/>
        <jvmarg value="-Djava.security.policy=policy"/>
        <arg value="localhost"/>
        <classpath>
            <pathelement location="dist/client.jar"/>
        </classpath>
    </java>
</target>
```

And then I would do something like `ant runClient` to launch the application "client.Client" with the jvmargs specified in the XML.. is there an SBT equivalent, or a way for SBT to hook into Ant to do this?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can use [Sbt Tasks](http://www.scala-sbt.org/release/docs/Detailed-Topics/Tasks) to do that. A task you define can depend on other tasks and/or settings (e.g, your project base directory):

```
import sbt._
import Keys._

object TestBuild extends Build {
  lazy val runClient = TaskKey[Unit]("runClient", "run client")

  lazy val root = Project("Test", file("."),
    settings = Defaults.defaultSettings ++ Seq(
    runClient <<= baseDirectory map {
      base =>
        val clientWebCodebase = base / "yourpath"
        val opts = Seq("-Djava.rmi.server.codebase=" + clientWebCodebase,
          "-Djava.security.policy=policy",
          "-cp", "dist/client.jar",
          "client.Client", "localhost"
        )
        Fork.java.fork(None, opts, None, Map(), false, StdoutOutput)
      }
    )
  )
}
```

Having such task definition you can run it either with:

```
sbt runClient
```

or in sbt shell:

```
>runClient
```

You'll even be able to use Tab completion: runC + tab :)